# Install and start Apache server automatically while launching an Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, ubuntu-18.04, autoscaling, amazon-ami

I am able to install apache server on Ubuntu instances by connecting to them with Putty.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

To avoid this manual process, I want to specify this install command in userdata. It will also be useful when I specify this in the AMI/Launch configuration when using Auto-scaling.

I have tried both SSH commands and shell scripting, but am unable to get the apache installed automatically while launching.

[image]

How can I write the userdata so that I can install and start the Apache server automatically while launching the ubuntu instance?

Comment: Why are you using yum in your userdata block? Ubuntu uses apt-get

Comment: I think that's a mistake. Should I use apt-get install apache2 ?

Comment: If you're doing `sudo apt-get install apache2` when you putty in and it works, then that's what you need to be doing when you use User Data.

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get install apache2 in userdata. But the newly launched instance does not have apache installed. I checked the folder with WinSCP. The var folder does not have the www folder.

Comment: Putty in and check if apache is installed `apache2 -v`.
You can also check the user-data script log at `/var/log/cloud-init.log` and `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the script below to install and start the apache server on Ubuntu ec2 instance launch.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install -y apache2
sudo systemctl start apache2
sudo systemctl enable apache2
```